# How to create our own TAG in AIML?

Tags: chatbot, aiml

bot in Python for which I need to create custom tag in AIML. I have created some basic skeleton but I need to work for advancement.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: What kind of tag do you want to create? In general if you want to add a new tag, you will have to modify the AIML interpreter and it won't be standard AIML. Another approach may be to write a new category that does the same thing as your new tag, and <srai> the new category instead.